# Standard practices for having multiple pages in a react app?

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a 1 page React app. Most of the interaction is on this page however I also want to add an "about" page. I am using create-react-app. So what are the standard practices for this? In know in html I would just make a new html page and link to it. In React I could just switch to render the new component and not the old ones when the "about" link is clicked however this is still on the same page and would make "back" not work right? What do you do for a small 2 page app and a large million page app?

Answer (score 2):

You need [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) in order to achive this. Then you can define multiple Routes that render different components depending on the current `location`. It also keeps track of the browser history.